# Strange issue 'Cannot find type 'RCTResponseSenderBlock' in scope' on Swift module React Native

Tags: objective-c, swift, react-native

I have a very strange problem: "Can't find the type RCTResponseSenderBlock in scope." It's strange, because in one case it is there and in the other it doesn't, looks like a bug.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHXlJ.png) is screenshot  issue.

This my Objective-C file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"
#import <React/RCTEventEmitter.h>
#import <React/RCTConvert.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(BLEclass, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(addEvent:(NSString *)name callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback )

@end
```

And this my Swift file, where i have issue :

```
import Foundation

@objc(BLEclass)
class BLEclass: NSObject{
  @objc(addEvent:callback:)
    func addEvent(_ name: String,_ callback:RCTResponseSenderBlock){
      NSLog("%@", name);
      let resultsDict = [
           "name" : name
           ];
      callback([NSNull(),resultsDict])
     }
}
```

If you know how to fix it, please write answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had this same issue and discovered I had to add the import to my main bridge file.

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <React/RCTViewManager.h>
```

I out which file was set by looking at the Build settings under **Swift Compiler - General** -> **Objective-C Bridging Header** which appears to be the default for the app.

Comment: What if in my xCode settings I have a blank for Objective-C Bridging Header?

Comment: add #import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <React/RCTViewManager.h>

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by adding

```
#import <React/RCTViewManager.h>
#import <React/RCTConvert.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

to Pods>Development Pods>react-native-rsa-native>RNRSA-Bridging-Header